# Python using Selenium lost count of a In range

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I'm trying to get the HTML of many pages on a website more than a thousand. 
My script is working but for no reason after a random number of page recuperate the script go to the next page. He does not take in the count all the page I want to get.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import time
 import os.path


   classes = ["sup","spé","b1","b2","b3","2C",
  "2A","2D","m1","m2","m3","2B","3C","3B",'3D',"3A"]


def CrawlingAll():


for  Classes in classes :

    dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    print(dir)
    filename = os.path.join(dir, 'Fiche', Classes)
    print(filename)
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        os.makedirs(filename)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    #Identification

    driver.get("https://username:pw@web.esme.fr/sas/common/archives.aspx")



    year = driver.find_element_by_id("sas_SelectionPlaceHolder__anneeSelect")
    year.send_keys("1998")

    classe = driver.find_element_by_id("sas_SelectionPlaceHolder_nomClasse")
    classe.send_keys(Classes)

    search = driver.find_element_by_id("sas_SelectionPlaceHolder__btnSubmit")
    search.click()

    #iteration du clicks des fiches eleves
    try:
        for i in range(1, 10000):
            fiche = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="liste"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[4]/a'%(i))
            fiche.click()

            driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1]) #switch vers la pop up
            source_code = driver.page_source #recuperation du code source de la pop up
            driver.close() #fermeture de la pop up
            driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0]) #retour a la fenetre principale


    #Ecriture des fiches html / eleves
            with open("%s/file-"%filename + str(i) + ".html", 'wb') as f:
                f.write(source_code.encode('utf-16'))
                f.close()

    except:
        print ("======DONE======")

    driver.close() #fermeture de la fenetre principale



def Crawlingclasses():






print("Select the class your want to crawl:  ")
print(classes)
Classe = input ()

print("Select when do you want to start crawling ex: 2015:  ")
Year = input()

dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print (dir)
filename = os.path.join(dir,'Fiche',Classe)
print (filename)


if not os.path.exists(filename):
    os.makedirs(filename)




driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Identification

driver.get("https://username:pw@web.esme.fr/sas/common/archives.aspx")

# Remplissage des boxs

# ================================= CRAWLING SUP =================================

year = driver.find_element_by_id("sas_SelectionPlaceHolder__anneeSelect")
year.send_keys(Year)

classe = driver.find_element_by_id("sas_SelectionPlaceHolder_nomClasse")
classe.send_keys(Classe)

search = driver.find_element_by_id("sas_SelectionPlaceHolder__btnSubmit")
search.click()

# iteration du clicks des fiches eleves
try:
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        fiche = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="liste"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[4]/a' % (i))
        fiche.click()

        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])  # switch vers la pop up
        source_code = driver.page_source  # recuperation du code source de la pop up
        driver.close()  # fermeture de la pop up
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])  # retour a la fenetre principale

        # Ecriture des fiches html / eleves
        with open("%s/file-"%filename + str(i) + ".html", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(source_code.encode('utf-16'))
            f.close()

except:
    print("======DONE======")

driver.close()  # fermeture de la fenetre principale
```

The number of pages is trying to get is here try:

> `for i in range(1, 10000):`

Any idea why selenium skipping many pages?

Comment: Does it produce any error? if it does what was it? if it didn't produce any errors, then what's the content of the file created?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear enough. The script produces no errors but for example: if I launch the "CrawlingAll" function it will crawl a random number of Item I want to get. Can be 400 or 200 on 1000. No error occurs and then it's just switched on the next  word of the list  and do the same things

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, there is no random element in it, you click links from 1 to 10000 and extract the page source, the only way it could skipped any of that is if it failed at your try... except block, try print i at your try ..except block and see where it failed.

Comment: I can know where it fails with the number of extracted page sources but I don't know why ..... Like I said i could stop at 200 pages and the next time at 400

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your code catches error but you didn't print the error message on your try except block, it's hard to tell what kind of error.

For now I suggest skipping an iteration if error encountered rather than skipping entire loop :

```
import sys

for i in range(1, 10000):
    try:
        fiche = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="liste"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[4]/a' % (i))
        fiche.click()

        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])  # switch vers la pop up
        source_code = driver.page_source  # recuperation du code source de la pop up
        driver.close()  # fermeture de la pop up
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])  # retour a la fenetre principale

        # Ecriture des fiches html / eleves
        with open("%s/file-"%filename + str(i) + ".html", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(source_code.encode('utf-16'))
            f.close() 
    except:
        print("Error at iteration %s:"%i, sys.exc_info()[0])
```